# imagemagick creating one big image by piling up thousand of images of the same width?

Tags: image-manipulation, imagemagick

I've got a few tens of thousands of images all of 2000 pixel width, and I would like to pile them up in one big image of summed up height and 2000 pixel width. I guess there must be a way to do that with imagemagick but I couldn't find a way to script it out for tens of thousands of images.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Mosaic style? With each image a couple pixels across?

Comment: just one under the other, with spacing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like a job for the [`montage`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php) command.

```
montage -tile 1 -geometry +0+0 *.jpg ../big.jpg
```

Comment: works wonders, thx